# How to hide some of the years in UIDatePicker in Swift?

Tags: swift, uidatepicker, custom-datetimepicker

I need to restrict the years in UIDatePicker, i.e set year is hidden if the year is more than our maximum date.

For this I already tried like myDatePicker.maximumDate=NSDate()

My date picker like [UIDatePickerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXLSD.png)

Now how can I remove or hide the year values more than(i.e 2016) our maximum date.

Thankyou

Comment: If it is set as the maximum date, users won't be able to scroll beyond that (it will just go back to the maximum date).  This is the behaviour of the UIDatePicker.  Why do you need to hide the dates beyond that?

Comment: @WilliamGP thank you for immediate reply.  Suppose with out hiding the year values beyond maximum date then user try scroll year component that's why I want to show year component upto maximum date only.

Comment: Yes, but it will just automatically scroll back to the maximum date.

Comment: @WilliamGP thank you for your reply again. Automatically scroll back to the maximum date is working fine for me this is not my problem. I need to hide the beyond the dates(i.e minimum date and maximum date)

Comment: If that is really what you want - I think you have to build a custom picker yourself using UIPickerView. Per iOS docs, " You cannot customise the appearance of Date Pickers" - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIDatePicker-SW3

Comment: @WilliamGP sorry for lately reply and thank you for this info. Now I will work on that.

Answer (score 1):

If that is really what you want - I think you have to build a custom picker yourself using UIPickerView.

[Per iOS docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker), "The appearance of UIDatePicker is not customizable."

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I will post my code as soon as Now I am working on it. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

you need to set validation on picker. so set the maximum date and minimum date of picker.
////

```
 self.datePicker.minimumDate = minDate;
    self.datePicker.maximumDate = maxDate;
```

Comment: ankit thank you for immediate reply. I already set min 01/01/2011 and max date is currentdate in storybaord. But still beyond the dates are showing in date picker so how can I hide/remove that dates.

Comment: welcome if its work than please upword my answer and accept it.